# How do i send a user to another page using header if session is empty?

Tags: php, session

I am making a form over a few pages that will send me an email at the end but i don’t want people going to other pages if they have not inputted their IGN (in game name) so i have tried to put it into a session. My problem is checking the session as i can’t get it to send the user back to the main page if the session is empty here is my code so far.

```
<?php session_start();
  $_SESSION['IGN']=$_POST['IGN'];
  if ($_SESSION['IGN']="")  {
    header('Location: Index.php');
  }
?>
```

Is it that im checking the session wrong? Can you take a look and help me please :-)

Comment: Oh you didn't. This question can be closed - it's typo in ==

Comment: @Skuta Thanks for pointing that out i should of seen that!

Comment: I see a potential issue with logic of your code. Something to think about: the code could be checking the correctness of IGN as well. Just pull all IGNs from database and check if it exists. What if I try to sql-inject your site and use a special code in IGN? I hope it accounts for such situations.

Comment: @Skuta It is sending it via email there will be no database involved it gets the IGN from a textbox on the "index.html". Although i have run into a problem when i try to go to the next question from the first it for some reason it sends it back to the index page. When i remove the check at the top of the first question it lets me go to question 2 do you know why that is?

Comment: I'd need to see the code

Comment: @Skuta Thankyou for the reply but it is fixed i asked a freind and they said the 'if ($_SESSION['IGN']=="")' needed to be 3 === so i tried it and it worked :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to do:

```
 if ( $_SESSION['IGN'] == "" )  {      // here you need to use "==" instead of "="
    header('Location: Index.php');
  }
```

Read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) how to compare.

Also you can check in such way:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['IGN']) && !empty($_SESSION['IGN']))  {
    header('Location: Index.php');
  }
```

Comment: Wow how did i miss that. I normaly pick up on things like this thanks for the very quick reply!

Comment: You can use `!isset($_SESSION['IGN']) && empty($_SESSION['IGN'])` instead of comparing the session with `""`

Comment: @Adam Azad,Thanks for review

Comment: `empty ()` checks whether variable is set internally. Since `empty ($var)` is equivalent to `!isset($var) || !$var` using only `empty ($var)` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php session_start();
  $_SESSION['IGN']=$_POST['IGN'];
  if ($_SESSION['IGN']=="" || is_null($_SESSION['IGN']))  {
    header('Location: Index.php');
  }
?>
```